# Cyclometer synonym for bike-computer?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-synonyms

I don't have anywhere near the rep to propose this directly, but cyclometer seems like a good synonym for bike-computer. It took me a few seconds to realize how I should tag a question I just posted - and if I'd had 300 rep I would've unwittingly created the cyclometer tag instead!

Answer (score 1):

Good point. Done. [cyclometer](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cyclometer) is now a synonym for [bike-computer](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bike-computer)